# hls aes encrypted video not playing after EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag on ios

Tags: ios, ios5, http-live-streaming

It looks like the ios doesn't like hls m3u8 files that mixes encrypted .ts files with the EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag.

Here is a test play list, it's a mix of two video. a preroll ad un encrypted and the main encrypted video. Both plays well separatly but when I put them together in a single m3u8, separated by a EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY, only the preroll is played and then the player stop.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXTINF:10,     
http://ixemes-ppweb.ixemes.com/prerollmain/vig_400-0.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://ixemes-ppweb.ixemes.com/prerollmain/vig_400-1.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:10,
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://ixemes-ppweb.ixemes.com/prerollmain/113760.key"
http://ixemes-ppweb.ixemes.com/prerollmain/02-0.ts
#EXTINF:10,     
http://ixemes-ppweb.ixemes.com/prerollmain/02-1.ts
#EXTINF:10,     
http://ixemes-ppweb.ixemes.com/prerollmain/02-2.ts
#EXTINF:10,     
http://ixemes-ppweb.ixemes.com/prerollmain/02-3.ts
#EXTINF:10,     
http://ixemes-ppweb.ixemes.com/prerollmain/02-4.ts
#EXTINF:10,     
http://ixemes-ppweb.ixemes.com/prerollmain/02-5.ts
#EXTINF:10,     
http://ixemes-ppweb.ixemes.com/prerollmain/02-6.ts
#EXTINF:10,     
http://ixemes-ppweb.ixemes.com/prerollmain/02-7.ts
#EXTINF:10,     
http://ixemes-ppweb.ixemes.com/prerollmain/02-8.ts
#EXTINF:10,     
http://ixemes-ppweb.ixemes.com/prerollmain/02-9.ts
#EXTINF:10,     
http://ixemes-ppweb.ixemes.com/prerollmain/02-10.ts
#EXTINF:10,     
http://ixemes-ppweb.ixemes.com/prerollmain/02-11.ts
#EXTINF:2,      
http://ixemes-ppweb.ixemes.com/prerollmain/02-12.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I have tryed with two un-encrypted videos and it works. And I see nothing in the HLS specs that says it's forbidden to use the EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag with encrypted videos : https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-08#section-6.3.3

So I guess it's apple implementation of it's own specs that is wrong, but maybe it's me doing it wrong.

I have made a quick html page to test it (open it in safari on any ios5 device) : http://ixemes-ppweb.ixemes.com/prerollmain/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I noticed your EXT-X-KEY doesn't have an IV term, a.k.a. an initialization vector. This is supported by the standard, e.g.:

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://priv.example.com/key.php?r=52",IV=0x9c7db8778570d05c3177c349fd9236aa
```

If this is missing, here's how https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2288/_index.html says the player should pick the IV:

> The default Initialization Vector for media encryption (if none is
>   specified) is the sequence number of the media file. You should
>   specify an Initialization Vector value, and not rely on sequence
>   numbers. The main reason for this is portability. For example, if you
>   change where the segment appears in the playlist (e.g. inserting an
>   ad), that changes its sequence number, requiring a re-encrypt.

On my team we were having trouble figuring out why encrypted content with inserted ads weren't playing. We had an example of encrypted content that played:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans.key"
#EXTINF:11,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-1.ts
#EXTINF:7,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-2.ts
#EXTINF:7,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-3.ts
#EXTINF:8,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-4.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-5.ts
#EXTINF:6,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-6.ts
#EXTINF:9,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-7.ts
#EXTINF:7,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-8.ts
#EXTINF:9,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-9.ts
#EXTINF:8,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-10.ts
#EXTINF:8,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-11.ts
#EXTINF:8,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-12.ts
#EXTINF:6,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-13.ts
#EXTINF:9,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-14.ts
#EXTINF:5,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-15.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

You can try this at http://demo.theplatform.com/dev/m3u8/encrypted.m3u8. But then when we inserted content before it, like this, it didn't play:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=NONE
#EXTINF:10.01,
http://ne.edgecastcdn.net/0008B0/mps/Inkola_VMS/20/687/15_WordIsOut_UPFW1764H_1080p_20802040_m3u8_video_480x0_400000_primary_audio_eng_2_x5e1c9dd7b9834f38a319d348e1a5f9ee_00001.ts
#EXTINF:5.088,
http://ne.edgecastcdn.net/0008B0/mps/Inkola_VMS/20/687/15_WordIsOut_UPFW1764H_1080p_20802040_m3u8_video_480x0_400000_primary_audio_eng_2_x5e1c9dd7b9834f38a319d348e1a5f9ee_00002.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans.key"
#EXTINF:11,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-1.ts
#EXTINF:7,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-2.ts
#EXTINF:7,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-3.ts
#EXTINF:8,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-4.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-5.ts
#EXTINF:6,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-6.ts
#EXTINF:9,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-7.ts
#EXTINF:7,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-8.ts
#EXTINF:9,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-9.ts
#EXTINF:8,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-10.ts
#EXTINF:8,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-11.ts
#EXTINF:8,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-12.ts
#EXTINF:6,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-13.ts
#EXTINF:9,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-14.ts
#EXTINF:5,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-15.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

This URL is http://demo.theplatform.com/dev/m3u8/mix.m3u8. The problem, we figured out, was because we added two segments, the media sequence number was now off by 2. If you explicitly set the IV to "0x00000000000000000000000000000001", like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=NONE
#EXTINF:10.01,
http://ne.edgecastcdn.net/0008B0/mps/Inkola_VMS/20/687/15_WordIsOut_UPFW1764H_1080p_20802040_m3u8_video_480x0_400000_primary_audio_eng_2_x5e1c9dd7b9834f38a319d348e1a5f9ee_00001.ts
#EXTINF:5.088,
http://ne.edgecastcdn.net/0008B0/mps/Inkola_VMS/20/687/15_WordIsOut_UPFW1764H_1080p_20802040_m3u8_video_480x0_400000_primary_audio_eng_2_x5e1c9dd7b9834f38a319d348e1a5f9ee_00002.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans.key",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000001
#EXTINF:11,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-1.ts
#EXTINF:7,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-2.ts
#EXTINF:7,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-3.ts
#EXTINF:8,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-4.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-5.ts
#EXTINF:6,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-6.ts
#EXTINF:9,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-7.ts
#EXTINF:7,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-8.ts
#EXTINF:9,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-9.ts
#EXTINF:8,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-10.ts
#EXTINF:8,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-11.ts
#EXTINF:8,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-12.ts
#EXTINF:6,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-13.ts
#EXTINF:9,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-14.ts
#EXTINF:5,
http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/oceans_aes/oceans_aes-audio=65000-video=2042000-15.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Then it works. You can try this as http://demo.theplatform.com/dev/m3u8/mix_fixed.m3u8. So maybe that was the issue you were running into.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it looks like it's not related to the encrytion of the main video but more how the main video is encoded. I don't have control on how the main video is encoded. I only encoded (and chuncked) myself  the preroll video for testing purpose.

If i mix the preroll with the same main video but un encrypted, it doesn't work also.
if i mix two video encoded by the same exteral encoder, encrypted (or not) it doesn't work.
Don't know whats wrong with then encoding parameters of the external encoder, but the discontinuity tag doesn't works it.

But if i encode myself both video (preroll and main), encrypt the main one, and put them in a single m3u8 file using the discontinuity tag, it works.

So there is still something wrong of how ios handles the discontinuity tag and doesn't fully reset the player parameters, but at least it's possible to insert a un encrypted preroll video before an encrypted one.

Comment: For those who are interested here is the avconv (ffmpeg) command line I used to encode properly the video : avconv -i 40361740.mpg -s 320x240 -f mpegts -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -b:a 82k -strict experimental -b:v 320k -bufsize:v 70000  -minrate:v 290k -maxrate:v 360k   40361740_400.ts